# How to interpret notation with multiple infinite operators of indexed families $\bigcup_n \bigcap_m A_{n,m}$ and $\bigcap_n \bigcup_m A_{n,m}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was given: $$A_{n,m}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \ \middle|\  \frac{n-1}{m+1}\leq x < n + m\right\}, \quad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
And tasked with finding sets:
$$\bigcup_n \bigcap_m A_{n,m}\quad\quad\bigcap_n \bigcup_m A_{n,m}$$
But I don't know how to approach chaining infinite operators.

Does the $\bigcup_n \bigcap_m A_{n,m}$ mean a set of elements that satisfy condition for every $m$ and any $n$ and $\bigcap_n \bigcup_m A_{n,m}$ is a set of $x$s that satisfy the condition for any $m$ and every $n$?

Similarly, I can't interpret multiple infinite operators in problem below:
Let $T = \bigcup_{s\in S}T_s$ and  $\mathcal{K}$ be a family of all subsets of $T$ that have at least one common element with each of $\;T_s$ sets.
Prove that if $\mathcal{K} \neq \emptyset$:
$$\bigcup_{s\in S}\bigcap_{t\in T_s}A_t=\bigcap_{Y\in \mathcal{K}}\bigcup_{t\in Y}A_t$$

Comment: $$ \bigcap_{n} \bigcup_{m} A_{n,m} = \bigcap_{n} \left[ \bigcup_{m} A_{n,m} \right], $$ *n'est-ce pas*?  So evaluate the inner term first, then continue from there.  Can you specify the question more?

Comment: for instance: does $\bigcup_n \bigcap_m A_{n,m}$ is a set of $x$s that satisfy $$A_{n,m}=\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \ \middle|\  \frac{n-1}{m+1}\leq x < n + m\right\}, \quad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$ for every $m$ and any $n$.

Comment: Your quantifiers are imprecise; I would interpret "$x$s that satisfy ___ for every $m$ and any $n$" as "$\forall m \forall n, x\in A_{n,m}$ which is $\bigcap\bigcap$ instead.  Hint: In both $\bigcap_n \bigcup_m A_{n,m}$ and $\bigcup_n\bigcap_m A_{n,m}$, consider $n$ "fixed" for the inner union/intersection over $m$. With $n$ fixed, the $A_{n,m}$ are nested half-open intervals, so the intersection over $m$ is just the smallest such set (if such a set exists, check!), and the union over $m$ is either the largest set if such a set exists, or the limit of the sets as $m\to \infty$.